# DataSet не сохраняет изменения в БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Всем привет. Не могу понять в чем дело. Есть удаленная БД MSSQL SqlServer 2008r2, через DataSet  добаляю новую строку, заполняю ее данными, подтверждаю. А в оригинальной БД ничего не меняется. Почему так ? Помогите пожалуйста.

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.130.147;Initial Catalog=AutoLot1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Администратор;Password=blablabla");
        SqlDataAdapter sqda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [Inventory]; select * from [Customers];select * from [Orders]", sc);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqda.Fill(ds);
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dr[0] = 555; dr[1] = "VAZ"; dr[2] = "blue"; dr[3] = "Citten";

        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);

        dr.AcceptChanges();
        ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
        ds.AcceptChanges();
        Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1][1]);
        Console.WriteLine(ds.HasChanges());
```

`sqda.Update(ds);` не помогает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сохранения данных используйте метод SqlDataAdapte.Update(ваш датасет). https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/at8a576f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Не помогло. Только что попробовал

Comment: У SqlDataAdapter должна быть настроена команда UpdateCommand https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Но вот у меня ума не хватает понять, а что нужно присвоить свойству UpdateCommand ? Могли бы вы, пожалуйста, привести какой-нибудь пример с UpdateCommand. Я просто думал, что компилятор сам генерирует все команды на основании моих действий с DataTable в DataSet

Answer (score 1):

Здесь сложного на самом деле ничего нет. Вам нужно всего лишь написать параметризованный SQL запрос, который обновляет данные в нужной таблице. В приведенной мной ссылке это и демонстрируется.

Предположим у Вас есть таблица People с полями ID, Name. В данном случае, запрос может выглядеть так:

```
 // Ваш адаптер для таблицы People.
 SqlDataAdapter peopleAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

 // Команда Update.
 var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE People SET ID = @ID, Name = @Name;", connection);  

 // Описываем параметры команды. 
 command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "ID");
 command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name");

 // Выставляем команду адаптеру.
 peopleAdapter.UpdateCommand = command;
```

В принципе на этом все. Не забудь по аналогии реализовать команды, SELECT, INSERT, DELETE. (*некоторые команды, такие как UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE можно реализовать автоматически*)

```
// Обновляем данные в БД.
peopleAdapter.Update(dataSet);
```

Comment: О, спасибо, добрый человек. Теперь вроде как ясно ястало.